# I have a few issues if you could help please

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Issue 1
For some reason, in my SharePoint list, the cascading dropdown menu doesn't work. It just gives all possible selection options determined in the Choice filter. I think it is linked to the Choice filter format however, I need a way to get this working as some of the selection items are extensive.
[image]

Issue 2
Again, linked to the same list, when multiple selections are made using the MultiChoice control the selections are added to the list but with a comma (which doesnt look very good). Can a space be inserted after the column or even better, each selection listed on a different line?
[image]

Ideally, looking for a no code solution.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. And try to give them relevant titles and tags!

Answer (score 0):

For your 2nd question, some where you have to replace comma with space. i dont think thats possible without any code(calculated colmun too doesn't support multi choice field). if you consider adding jquery in conent editor web part, you can try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  //chk syntax errors

  $(".ms-vb:contains(',')").each(function(){
    var str= $(this).html();
    var formatted= str.replace(","," ");
    $(this).html(formatted);
  });
});
```

or you can write jquery function by using column title.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for the tip on Issue 2. The problem is I have little experience of using jquery so will need to read up and have a little 'play'. I dont suppose there is a similar code that not only removes the comma, but enters each selection on a different line. Such as:                        Selection1                                                  selection2                                                        selection3 etc....                                                   Many thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try this code? yes this code enters each line, becoz this code selects td of .ms-vb class.  Add this code in Content Editor web part

Comment: Hi. I am not sure how I would go about doing this.

Comment: I dont suppose you could provide brief instructions?...please

Comment: its simple , please google for " how to add jquery in content editor web part". you have to get a latest jquery plugin and refer it in your code.